# How can we deal with other web applications in shared domain improperly scoping cookies to parent domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies

In a corporate enterprise, we have several web applications.

- myapp.corp.com
- otherapp.corp.com
- oldapp.corp.com

The OtherApp is scoping its cookies (improperly) into the parent domain of corp.com.  This results in their users' browsers sending all of these cookies for their application to myapp since they are both within the corp.com scope.

In some cases, OtherApp has set cookies with special characters in its cookies that resulted in cookie parsing errors from OldApp.  This is a bug for OldApp as far as I am concerned, but it leads to several interesting questions.

If they end up setting fifty 4k cookies, I don't want that included in the traffic going to MyApp due to their improper scoping.  I have toyed with the idea of force-expiring their cookies via javascript as a nuclear option.

This poses a security risk to OtherApp, and could cause issues for MyApp as well, but I am unsure how soon anything will be done to address the issue.  Are there any other viable programmatic methods available for MyApp to protect itself from OtherApp's incorrectly scoped cookies?

Comment: This seems to be more of a management problem than programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're truly in a corporate enterprise environment, then the owners of OtherApp are probably dependent on the funding/approval of some corporate sponsor. Find out which executive decides to keep funding OtherApp, find out what matters to him/her, and make your case.

Chances are the executive cares about various KPI like uptime. If MyApp and OldApp have a direct impact on time and/or money, and they are threatened by the OtherApp problems, then bring that specific scenario up and let that executive tell the owners of OtherApp to get their act together.

Comment: I agree, and we will be taking a similar approach.  I would be curious if there were also some programatic method a developer could take to protect his / her site from "improperly scoped cookies" in the event that nothing changes.

Comment: Not really. MyApp isn't requesting the cookies - the browser is simply sending all the cookies that it believes to be relevant to the domain it's visiting. So if you're concerned about the bandwidth portion of things, there's not much you can do. As far as security goes, just don't use the cookies.